# python coding issue for length converter

Tags: python, list, for-loop

why `if from_unit ==unit[0]` will return `found unit, in`? isn't the `unit[0]==['cm',0.01]`? this should not equal to `in`, right?**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W10de.png)

Following is my code:

```
def converter(value, from_unit='cm',to_unit='m'):
    units = [['m',1],['cm',0.01],['in',0.0254]]
    if from_unit != units[0][0]:
        print("conver to base unit")
        for unit in units[1:]:
            if from_unit == unit[0]:
                print("found unit ", unit[0])

print(converter(10,'in','cm'))
```

Comment: Please don't post code as a picture. Post it instead here on SO.

Comment: Your function does not return anything. It does not have a `return` statement. `print(converter(10,'in','cm'))` always prints `None`.

Comment: Why not place a `print(unit)` in your for loop and observe, what `unit` and `unit[0]` really is instead of guessing? Or try your code on [Pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Comment: sorry about the picture, I couldn't submit it no matter how I typed the code. first time using it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`if from_unit == unit[0]:` will only satisfy when the `for` loop reaches `units[2][0]`. That's why its printing `in` and not `cm`.

Comment: Thus is not true. The value of the formal parameter `from_unit` is 'in', not 'cm'.

Comment: Yes exactly ! This is what I mean. Since, `if from_unit == unit[0]:` can only be True when `from_unit` is 'in' & that's why 'in' is getting printed. I don't understand the point of your down-vote though.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `from_unit` is `'in'`, because the second parameter is passed explicitly. If you called `converter(10)` (with only one parameter), the `from_unit` would be `'cm'`.